# ¿Como hago para imprimir una tabla con los equivalentes decimal y binario?

Tags: c

El código ya lo tengo hecho, es el siguiente:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
int decimal, b[100], i, j, n;
printf("DECIMAL\t\tBINARIO\n0\t\t0\n");
for(decimal=1; decimal<=19; decimal++)
{
    printf("%d\n", decimal);
}

printf("\t\t");
for(decimal=1; decimal<=19; decimal++)
{
    i=0;
    n=decimal;
    while(n>0)
    {
        b[i]=n%2;//b[0]=0, b[1]=1
        n=n/2;//decimal=1, decimal=0
        i++;//i=1, i=2
    }
    for(j=i-1; j>=0; j--)
    {
        printf("%d", b[j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
return 0;
}
```

Quisiera imprimir la tabla equivalente de la siguiente forma:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero lo que logro únicamente con mi código es que los números binarios se impriman debajo del decimal y no debajo del binario.

Comment: Intentaste agregar el código de los dos `for` en uno solo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Pero lo que logro únicamente con mi código es que los números binarios se impriman debajo del decimal y no debajo del binario.

Lo que pasa es que las dos tabulaciones que haces solo afectan al primer número que se imprime en la iteración: `printf("\t\t");`. Por cada iteración del ciclo estás cambiando la linea de impresión: `printf("\n");`

Necesitas imprimir el número decimal y su equivalente a binario en **la misma linea**. Para esto tienes que imprimir en el mismo ciclo ambos valores. Esto se hace ubicando el ciclo `for` que imprime los números binarios dentro del que imprime los decimales.

```
int main(void) {
    int decimal;
    int b[100]; 
    int i,j,n;

    printf("DECIMAL\t\tBINARIO\n0\t\t0\n");

    for(decimal = 1;decimal <= 19;decimal++) {
        i = 0;
        n = decimal;

        while(n > 0) {
            b[i] = n % 2;//b[0]=0, b[1]=1
            n = n / 2;//decimal=1, decimal=0
            i++;//i=1, i=2
        }

        printf("%d\t\t",decimal);
        for(j = (i - 1);j >= 0;j--) {
            printf("%d",b[j]);
        }

        printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

### ¿Por qué se debe de hacer esto?

Hay que ponerle atención a estas lineas

```
printf("%d\t\t",decimal);
for(j = (i - 1);j >= 0;j--) {
    printf("%d",b[j]);
}

printf("\n");
```

La primera linea imprime el número **decimal**, además de dos tabulaciones para luego imprimir el **binario**. El ciclo `for` va a imprimir todos los números del array que almacena el número binario. Finalmente se cambia de linea con: `"\n"`, y luego sigue la otra iteración

```
Decimal|Tabulación|Tabulación|Binario|Cambio de linea
```

Por esto mismo se obtiene

```
DECIMAL         BINARIO
0               0
1               1
2               10
3               11
4               100
5               101
6               110
7               111
8               1000
9               1001
10              1010
11              1011
12              1100
13              1101
14              1110
15              1111
16              10000
17              10001
18              10010
19              10011
```

Espero haberte ayudado, saludos.